# How can I recursively rename files via bash-scripting?

Tags: bash, rename, mv

I'm trying to rename several different files in bash.
How to rename for example temp_1 to temp_01 until 09 (temp_9 to temp_09)?

I used sed but somehow didn't work.

I tried with this:

```
 for i in temp_?.txt; 
 do
   j=echo $i | sed 's/[^0-9]*/0[^0-9]*/g';
   mv "$i" "$j"; 
 done
```

Comment: "[...] but somehow didn't work" isn't very clear. What have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: for i in temp_?.txt; do j=`echo $i | sed 's/[^0-9]*/0[^0-9]*/g'`; mv  "$i" "$j"; done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify your `sed` command to something like

```
sed 's/[0-9]/0&/'
```

That will do the work for your example case.

Your command doesn't work because when you are trying to reference the matched string you actually don't: it's done with `&` (for the whole match) or numbered [references](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4).

Comment: @LevLevitsky Afraid I don't have the time to perfect this now, but I think something on the lines of these should also work and be a bit more compact: `rename 's/(temp_)([0-9])/\10\2/g' temp_?.txt`

Comment: @LevLevitsky Just realize right now that if I have something like temp_1_25 this will also affect 25. How to apply the change just to the position where the 1 is? Thanks.

Comment: @g256 `sed 's/temp_\([0-9]\)/temp_0\1/'` for example.

Answer (score 1):

No need for `sed`; just use what you know about the file names:

```
for i in {0..9}
do
   mv temp_$i.txt temp_0$i.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you are not capturing the output from sed, which you need to put inside backticks or `$( ... )`.  Plus, your RE is wrong, try this:

```
for i in temp_?.txt 
do  
    j=$(echo $i | sed 's/\([0-9]\{1,\}\)/0\1/g')
    mv "$i" "$j"   
done
```

Note: I would prefer to use the -E option to `sed` for Extended regular expressions, but I don't know if your `sed` supports it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape your variable assignment

```
j=`echo echo $i | sed 's/[^0-9]*/0[^0-9]*/g'`
```

also, you don't need the semicolons at the end of each statement, unless you have all the operations on one line